# audio recording in safari giving application/octate-stream as mime type

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, webapi, web-development-server

I am trying to record the user's recording from a mic using media recorder api and it is working fine in chrome but when i try to record same for the safari it is giving mime type as application/octate-stream.

I need to send base 64 of the recorded audio to server and my server did not accept the application/octate-stream mime type so i need to pass any valid mime type like mp4, mp3, wav or webm.

I am using core js in the flutter web for the recording.

I have tried applying type to the Blob but it is also not working.

example:-

```
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/mp4; codecs=opus" });
```